# conda doesnt recognize my virt env , while having two virl env on two anaconda versions 2 and 3?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda2 and Anaconda3, and both have virtual environments Envy2 and Envy3 respectively. When i tried to activate or install some packages in the virtual environment i created using anaconda 3, which is Envy3:

```
>> conda install -n Envy3 tensorflow
```

*it throws an error, no such environment*

```
>> daniel@Patr:~$source activate Envy3
Could not find conda environment: Envy3
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`
```

However i can only use the one  of Anaconda2, Envy2, Envy3 isn't recognized as virtual environment at all, This is the result of conda info envs :

```
>> daniel@Patr:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/daniel/anaconda2
Envy2                    /home/daniel/anaconda2/envs/Envy2
                         /home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Envy3
```

what should i do to use it? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: can you be more clear on stating problem and solution you tried ?

Comment: i need to install some packages in the virtual environment i created using anaconda 3, which is Envy3:
>> conda install -n Envy3 pygco  
it throws an error, no such environment